# How can I import the FreeBSD VM Current Snapshots into VMWare Workstation or VMWare Fusion?

Tags: vmware, freebsd

I'm trying to import any of the .raw, .vhd, or .vmdk images from ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/snapshots/VM-IMAGES/11.0-CURRENT/amd64/ into VMWare Worksation (on Windows) or VMWare Fusion (on Mac).  I'm running Workstation 8 and Fusion 6.

I've tried importing all three, creating a custom VM and choosing an existing disk, but it always fails with the error

> The file specified is not a virtual disk

Is anyone else able to get this working? If so, how?

Comment: Have you checked the checksums to make sure the files were downloaded correctly?

Comment: Yes, the sha256sums match

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible, snapshots are deltas from vm disks. So you need the original vm disk to use this snapshot.

Comment: I didn't mean snapshots in the VM sense, I meant Snapshots of the HEAD of the -CURRENT tree, as announced here: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-announce/2013-May/001478.html

Comment: Oh, sorry for the missunderstandig. I downloaded a vmdk file as well and try to open it in VMWare workstation. But I got the same error message. So it looks like the file is a very old version or not in correct format